# How to sort recycler view SQLite content

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a a view where a bunch of my Sqlite data is displayed. I recently added a column to my database called location_position. I have added a button to my relative layout so that when its clicked I want the data inside to be sorted in ascending format. I have tried following a few examples online but with the way my app is setup im struggling tom get it to work.

I have a routeView.java class and a routeAdapter

I would really apreciate if someone can show me how to have the content sorted when the button is clicked, or any resources with similar solutions

```
public class RouteView extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
routeAdapter routeAdapter;
ArrayList<String>  location_id, location_name, location_county, location_description, location_route, location_position;
MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
Button createPDFButton, btnNorth, southBtn;

Context mContext = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_view);

    Button southBtn = findViewById(R.id.button_south);
    
    southBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.sort(ArrayList);
        }
    });
   // btnRemove = findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);

    createPDFButton = findViewById(R.id.createPDFButton);
    location_id = new ArrayList<>();
    location_name =  new ArrayList<>();
    location_county = new ArrayList<>();
    location_description = new ArrayList<>();
    location_route = new ArrayList<>();
    location_position = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();

    createPDFButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (UserActivity.checkAppPermission(RouteView.this, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 1)){
               generatePDF(recyclerView);
           }

        }
    });
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        if(cursor.getString(4).equals("1")) {
            location_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
            location_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
            location_county.add(cursor.getString(2));
            location_description.add(cursor.getString(3));
            location_route.add(cursor.getString(4));
            location_position.add(cursor.getString(8));
        }
    }
    routeAdapter = new routeAdapter(this, this, location_id, location_name, location_county, location_description, location_route, location_position);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

and this is the route adapter class

```
public class routeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<routeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
//private final ClickListener listener;
private Context context;
MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
Activity activity;
private ArrayList location_id, location_name, location_county, location_description, location_position, location_route, location_image_url;
Button btnRemove;
String id, name, county, description;
routeAdapter(Activity activity, Context context,  ArrayList location_id, ArrayList location_name, ArrayList location_county,
             ArrayList location_description, ArrayList location_route, ArrayList location_position){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.location_id = location_id;
    this.location_name = location_name;
    this.location_county = location_county;
    this.location_description = location_description;
    this.location_position = location_position;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.location_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(location_id.get(position)));
    holder.location_name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(location_name.get(position)));
    holder.location_county_txt.setText(String.valueOf(location_county.get(position)));
    holder.location_description_txt.setText(String.valueOf(location_description.get(position)));



    holder.mainLayout2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RouteView.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(location_id.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("name", String.valueOf(location_name.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("county", String.valueOf(location_county.get(position)));
            intent.putExtra("description",String.valueOf(location_description.get(position)));
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()  { return location_id.size(); }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView location_id_txt, location_name_txt, location_county_txt, location_description_txt, added_to_route_txt, location_image_url;
        LinearLayout mainLayout2;
        Button btnRemove;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            location_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_id_txt);
            location_name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_name_txt);
            location_county_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_county_txt); 
            location_description_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_description_txt);
            mainLayout2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeping `ArrayList` for each property is a bad idea u will end up a having a Hulk size constructor. Create a POJO class and have all properties set there and use it as ArrayList of POJO . Also if u want to get free from this pain full cursor stuff you might wanna checkout `android-room`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic concept:

On clicking a button or whatever to sort the things in a specific order, you sort the ArrayList that contains the values reflected in the RecyclerView. Then you update/ recreate the RecyclerView to register the changes.